# Cannot redeclare class with wordpress and memcached

Tags: wordpress, memcached, php

Whenever my WordPress site gets a lot of traffic I get tons of these errors:

`[Tue Oct 29 22:23:23 2013] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] FastCGI: server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi" stderr: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class wp_facebookapiexception in /wp-content/plugins/all-in-one-event-calendar/lib/facebook-php-sdk/base_facebook.php on line 25, referer: http://example.com/the-article/`

PHP stops working and I must restart memcached and PHP-fpm, once the traffic lowers to normal i get no more of these errors

My server configuration is

```
Linux Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
PHP 5.4.21-1+debphp.org
memcache 3.0.8
APC config:
extension=apc.so
apc.filters = wp-cache-configi,wp-cache-base,lessc.inc
apc.include_once_override = 0
apc.shm_size=96M
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
```

Any ideas what might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding APC filters

`apc.filters = wp-cache-config,wp-cache-base,lessc.inc,base_facebook`